# Updating apps with admin.setAppProperties

Tags: facebook, api, admin

I am updating my applications using the API with admin.setAppProperties.

How do I set the "Page Tab Width" and the "Page Tab Image"? I cannot find this in any documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i hope you are not using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.setAppProperties/

Answer (score 0):

A bug has been reported on the same [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/284403804966080)

May be you should wait for this to happen using graph api

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the info. So it is not possible at the moment. Need to do it manually one by one then.